# Auto fit contained divs

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set up automatically resizable divs based on the content that will go into them. The code is kind of hackey but I was wondering if anyone could provide me some suggestions on getting it to work properly.

CSS:

```
.container { min-width:748px; margin-left:180px; margin-right:3px; border: 1px solid #210B61; border-top:none; }
.first_div { width:233px; background:#A9BCF5; border: 1px solid #210B61; float:left; overflow:auto; }
.second_div { background:#E0ECF8; overflow:hidden; }
.label_for_first_div { width:100px; text-align:left margin-left:5px; }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="first_div">
        <div class="label_for_first_div">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="second_div">

    </div>
</div>
```

The trouble with this is the first_div will not display inside the container without the use of the label_for_first_div. Getting the first div to fit the height of that container has been troubling too. Would using display:table; be my best option?

Comment: Your example has no content.

Comment: what do you mean? the first `div` has a fixed width and the other fills the remaining space?

Comment: @jmore009: yes that's correct. But it needs to obey a min-width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `calc()` to accomplish this

```
.container { 
   min-width:748px; 
   margin-right:3px; 
   border: 1px solid #210B61; 
   border-top:none; 
   overflow: hidden;
}

.first_div { 
   width:233px; 
   background:#A9BCF5; 
   float:left; 
}

.second_div {
   width: calc(100% - 233px);
   background:red; 
   float: left;
}
```

[**EXAMPLE 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/ot4sykcg/1/)

## **OR**

You can do this by setting the divs to `display: table-cell` and the parent to `display: table`

```
.container { 
    display: table;
    min-width:748px; 
    margin-right:3px; 
    border: 1px solid #210B61; 
    border-top:none; 
}
.first_div { 
    display: table-cell;
    width:233px; 
    background:#A9BCF5; 
}

.second_div {
    display: table-cell;
    background:red; 
}
```

[**EXAMPLE 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/ot4sykcg/2/)

Comment: The second Example works exactly as needed. Thank you so much.

Comment: you got it. glad to help